# "Graining" effect when embedding PNG with alpha transparency

Tags: php, transparency, gd, tcpdf, imagick

I'm trying to add a transparent image over a pdf file with TCPDF. However the function only works, when I call

```
 $this->Image($markupfile, 0, 0,  $s['w'],$s['h'] , '', '', '', true, 55);
```

with a very low dpi (the last argument) of less than around 60. This results in the image below, which displays some kind of graining effect. I can't set the dpi higher, because this interrupts the php execution, which seems to be yet another problem. 
Does anybody have any ideas what could be going wrong? Looking a the source of **[tcpdf](http://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/code/ci/146e4337cac1f27eb9ee1328e2e2091e5cd1fc4f/tree/tcpdf.php)** it uses either the **GD** or the **imagick** library for embedding png.

[image: transparency problem]

Comment: What is the image size (in pixels, or bytes)? Also, does the "interrupted PHP execution" return any errors - such as *memory exhausted*?

Comment: there is no error message (I also tried setting the maximum memory to 512MB instead of 128MB, but to no avail). The original png has a size of 8.08KB and dimensions of 803x568.

Comment: No error? Not even in the web server error log? What are the values of `$s['w']` and `$s['h']`?

Comment: (Check the actual page size in user units with `getPageDimensions()` and compare with `$s`. Ideally they should be more or less the same. If you specified user units in inches and `$s` in pixels, for example, then a memory error would be all too likely.

Comment: the values of $s['w'] and $s['h'] are the expected 297 and 210, the image also appears correctly resized, however with the graining effect. there is no error in the server logs which seems related. the only notable thing might be that a request to the script doesnt show up at all, neither in the access.logs nor the error.logs

Comment: OK... how about you supply an image with the correct pixel size, and set `resize` to `False` in the `Image` call? That ought at the very least to supply some more clues. I'm baffled; usually the symptoms you describe are due to a size (therefore, memory) error of some kind, but your parameters look correct.

Comment: setting the resize flag to false also breaks the execution, therefore I am unable to try that. setting the width and height to '' (empty string) just results in a very small image (however the original is the expected size, of 803x568).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19490/discussion-between-lserni-and-jcfrei)